# azure webhook to stream splunk data

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I want to schedule splunk report to an azure web-hook and persist it into Cosmos DB.(after from processing ) [This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-event-hub-cosmos-db) gave me some insight on how to process and persist data into cosmos db via the azure functions ( in java  ). To solve the next part of the puzzle I"m reaching out for some advise on how to go about:

1. How to setup and host a webhook on Azure ?
   Should I set a `HttpTrigger` , inside the `EventHubOutput` function and deploy it into the function app.? Or should I use the Webhook from Azure Event Grid ?(not clear on how to do this ). I'm NOT looking to stream any heavy volumes of data and want to keep the consumption cost low. So , which route should I take here?. Any pointers to tutorials will be of help here.
2. How do I handle a webhook data processing on `@EventHubOutput` ( [referring the java example in the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-event-hub-cosmos-db?tabs=bash#add-java-code)) ?. What is the setup and configuration I need to do here ? Any working examples will be of help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using just the `@HttpTrigger` and binding the output using `@CosmosDBOutput` to persist the data. Something like this , would like to know if there are any better approaches.

```
public class Function {

@FunctionName("PostData")
public HttpResponseMessage run(
        @HttpTrigger(
                name = "req",
                methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
                authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
                HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,

        @CosmosDBOutput( name = "databaseOutput", databaseName = "SplunkDataSource",
                         collectionName = "loginData", 
                         connectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnectionString")
                         OutputBinding<String> document,
                         final ExecutionContext context) { 
          context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

    // Parse the payload
    String data = request.getBody().get();

    if (data == null) {
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(
          "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body").build();
    } else {
        // Write the data to the Cosmos document.
        document.setValue(data);
        context.getLogger().info("Persisting payload to db :" + data);
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body(data).build();
    }
}
```